# Decomposition of a tensor under transformations

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-representations, representation-theory

To illustrate my question I'll take an example from theory of relativity:
An arbitrary 4-tensor $A^{ik}$ changes under a general coordinate transformation:
$$
    A'^{ik} = C^{i}_mC^{k}_n A^{mn}
$$
(latin indices go from 0 to 3).

Now if I take not an arbitrary 4-space transformation $C$ but an arbitrary 3-space rotation, it can be shown (I can only do it directly by hand) that symmetric stress-energy tensor $T^{ik}=T^{ki}$ "decomposes" into:

- 3-scalar $T^{00}$
- 3-vector $T^{0\alpha}$ (greek indices go from 1 to 3)
- 3-tensor $T^{\alpha\beta}$

An anti-symmetric EM-field tensor $F^{ik}=-F^{ki}$ "decomposes" into:

- 3-vector $F^{0\alpha}$
- 3-pseudo-vector $(-F^{23}, F^{13}, -F^{12})$

My question is: in general, if I have a tensor $A^{ijk...}$ with certain linear properties of symmetry
$$
    S^{lmn...}_{ijk...}T^{ijk} = 0
$$
and I take coordinate transformations $C$ how do I find which parts of $A^{ijk...}$ are independent under this transformation?

I know it has something to do with group theory, but all I've read so far have nothing to do with this (or I don't know how to apply it to this case). Could someone show an example or point me to a specific reading?

Comment: It seems to me that you are seeking the decomposition of representations of the Lorentz group on the tensors into the irreducible components (of a subgroup of it, the rotations), but I am not sure what your actual question is. All $k$-tensors decompose in *some* way into irreducible representations, but I'm not sure what your last equation is supposed to tell us, for example.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, yes, in the example I use decomposition into representations of the group of rotations. But I am interested in a general situation - an arbitrary group of coordinate transformations acting on tensors with any symmetry properties. How do I find this decomposition? (My last equation is supposed to show symmetry properties, e.g. for symmetric 2-tensor $T^{ik} - T^{ki} = 0$, for antisymmetric $F^{ik} + F^{ki}=0$)

Comment: Since representations depend heavily on the group in question, I believe the general answer you are seraching for  doesn't exist.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, That's sad :) If I narrow the class of transformations to linear and continuous (Lie groups), would it help?